# How to programmatically go to the previous route in vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

How to navigate to parent route programatically in vue-router.

```
$router.go(-1)
```

Works, but it send me to the previous route visited.

I expect the destination to be the parent route.

Comment: So if you were on `/photos/photo123`, you want a function that would take you to `/photos`?

Comment: use $route.matched, it will give you an object containing what you need (should be at first index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To navigate to the parent route:

```js
this.$router.push(this.$route.matched[1].parent.path)
```

This just works in my case.